# grunt command not found on travis-ci, but grunt and grunt-cli is installed

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, travis-ci

I'm getting failed build on travis saying **grunt: command not found**.

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.11"
  - "iojs"
before_install: npm install -g grunt-cli
install: npm install
before_script: grunt build
```

in my package.json in devDependencies I have `"grunt": "^0.4.5",`
and in scripts  this `"test": "grunt test"`

Any idea what am I missing? Locally all grunt tasks run ok.

Comment: Paste your PATH variable.

Comment: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/share/ant/bin   but how PATH variable can have any impact on this?

Comment: Path variable controls where to look when you write grunt.

Comment: Which grunt will show that if grunt cmd is in path

Comment: grunt runs fine locally and it installed via npm on travis

Comment: Just because it runs fine locally does not mean that Travis's PATH and your PATH is same. Try to run shell in travis with echo $PATH;which grunt.

Comment: thanks for help. I had a typo in the config :)